# Querying the subcollections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is the structure:

- accounts (collection)

  - amazon (document)

    - items (collection)

      - amazon1month (document)

What am I trying to do?

I'm trying to query the collection accounts and find all the documents where 'brand-id' field matches 'amazonbrand'. This field is available inside the last collection in one of the documents. But, my application is structured such that, I need to query the first collection to scan through all the documents inside all the sub collections and get me the document with a matching parameter.

I'm not sure if this is even possible. Please advice me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore queries can only filter on data that is inside the documents they potentially return. So you can't perform a query on `accounts` and in there filter on data from the `items` subcollection.

The most common approaches to accomplish the use-case are:

- Perform a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) on `items`, then loop over those results and determine the unique parent `accounts` documents.
- Duplicate the data you want to query on in each `accounts` document, and then query on that.

Which one to use depends on your exact use-case, so you might want to try both and see what works best for you.